# Compare 2 numerals and copy only similar part sed/grep/awk

Tags: bash, scripts

Supposing I have a array called `a`. There are 2 entries in a array `a[1]` and `a[2]`.So each element contains a numeral value. Both these values have a similar starting numbers however they have different endings. I am to copy the similar part and ignore the rest.

So as an **example**

```
$ echo ${a[1]}
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256

$ echo ${a[2]}
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276
```

I need some command to compare these elements and then copy only the similar part **until the first non matching field**.
ie., in this example

#### OUTPUT

```
similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.232
```

#### Another example

```
$ echo ${a[1]}
.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.2344.454545

$ echo ${a[2]}
.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.3234.454545
```

#### OUTPUT for this example

```
similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.759
```

Comment: a[1] and a[2] are arrays or entries in the array?

Comment: `a` is my array name and 1,2 are index positions in them where these numerals are stored

Comment: how yo declare this array could you please edit your answer and list declaration

Comment: ok then those are entries and not arrays!!! Please edit your question and show that

Comment: Done. Is it right now?

Comment: Ok this is better

Comment: @SamFlynn I have an idea with awk but need to test it. I'm on mobile right now.  Will be on my computer in two hours.  Basic idea: printf ${array [1]} ${array [2]} | awk '{ for ( x=1; x <=NF/2; x+=NF/2) { if ( $x == $(x + NF/2) ) print $x;}}; I think iy either needs -F'.' flag or gsub ('.',' ') in the code to remove all dots and use space as separator

Comment: I assume that in case of e.g. `${a[1]}=".1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.885"` and `b="${.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.885}"` you want `.1.3.6.1.4.1.232` and not `.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.885`, correct?

Comment: yes your assumption is correct.

Comment: @SamFlynn So I've noticed that in the examples you posted , the two array elements always have same amount of numbers, for instance in 1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276 there is eight number sets and .1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256 . Is there gonna be instances where number 1 has different amount of number sets, like .1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256 (8 sets) compared against .1.3.6.1.4.1.759.2344.454545 ( 9 sets ) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973088/longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings-in-bash):

> In sed, assuming the strings don't contain any newline characters:
>
> ```
> string1="test toast"
> string2="test test"
> printf "%s\n%s\n" "$string1" "$string2" | sed -e 'N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1/'
> ```

This assumes that the strings themselves don't contain newlines.

Therefore you can do:

```
printf "%s\n" "${a[1]}" "${a[2]}" | sed -r 'N;s/^(.*)(\..*)?\n\1.*$/\1/'
```

The `(\..*)` *should* eliminate a trailing `.` from the common section.

---

The solution involves two parts:

- Getting `sed` to work across two lines. This is done using `N`, and can be avoided if a character is guaranteed to be not in the input. For example, because spaces are not present in the elements as given, we can instead use:

  ```
  printf "%s " "${a[1]}" "${a[2]}" | sed -r 's/^(.*)(\..*)? \1.*$/\1/'
  ```

  Essentially, the character or string separating the two elements in the output should be used after `%s` in the `printf` formatting string, and before `\1` in the regular expression.
- Finding a repeating string using regex. The trick for this is well-known, and is always a variation of:

  ```
  (.*)\1
  ```

  `.*` matches any set of characters, and `()` groups them for later reference, by `\1`. Thus `(.*)\1` is any sequence of characters followed by itself.

Comment: o_O to short :P +1

Comment: There is a trailing `.`: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.`

Comment: @A.B. Try update.

Comment: now it's perfect

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Perl way. The idea is to split both input strings into separate arrays and iterate over the arrays, saving any entries that are identical in both:

```
perl -le '@A=split(//,$ARGV[0]);@B=split(//,$ARGV[1]); 
          for $i (0..$#A){$A[$i] eq $B[$i] ? push @S,$A[$i] : last} 
          print @S' "${a[0]}" "${a[1]}"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.
```

That, however, includes the trailing `.`. Your output doesn't (despite its being the same in both variables), so if you want to remove it, use this instead:

```
$ perl -le '@A=split(/\./,$ARGV[0]);@B=split(/\./,$ARGV[1]); 
            for $i (0..$#A){$A[$i] eq $B[$i] ? push @S,$A[$i] : last} 
            print join ".",@S' "${a[0]}" "${a[1]}"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.759
```

#### Explanation

- `-le` : add a new**l**ine to each call of `print` and run the script given by `-e`.
- `@A=split(//,$ARGV[0])` : `$ARGV[0]` is the first argument given on the command line. This will split it, making each character an element in array `@A`.
- `@B=split(//,$ARGV[1]);` : same as above but for the 2nd argument and array `@B`.
- `for $i (0..$#A)` : a for loop. This sets `$i` to 0 and increments it by one until it has the value of the number of elements in array `@A` (`$#A`). This is a simple way of iterating over all elements in an array since `$A[$i]` will be `$A[0]`, `$A[1]`, ... , `$A[$#A]`.
- `$A[$i] eq $B[$i] ? push @S,$A[$i] : last` : this is a C-style shorthand notation. The general format is `foo ? bar : baz` and means "if `foo` is true, do `bar`, else do `baz`. Here, we are testing whether the `n`th (or `$i`th, in this case) element of array `@A` is the same as the corresponding one from array `@B`. If it is, we add it to the third array, `@S`. If it isn't, we exit the loop with `last`.
- `print @S` : print the array `@S`, the shared elements.

The two solutions are very similar, the only difference is that `@A=split(/\./,$ARGV[0])` will split on `.`, removing them from the resulting array and `print join ".", @S` will print all elements of `@S` with a `.` between them.

Comment: Master of perl =)

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` (`gawk`):

```
awk -F. '{printf "%s","similar part is "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {first[i-1]=$i} getline; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {second[i-1]=$i} for(i=0;i<length(first);i++) {if(first[i] == second[i]) {result=result first[i]"."}} printf "%s",substr($result,0,length(result)-1)"\n"}' <<< "$a"$'\n'"$b"
```

Or more readable:

```
awk -F. '{
    printf "%s","similar part is "
  }
  {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      first[i-1]=$i
    }

    getline;

    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      second[i-1]=$i
    }

    for(i=0;i<length(first);i++) {
      if(first[i] == second[i]) {
        result=result first[i]"."
      }
    }
    printf "%s",substr($result,0,length(result)-1)"\n"
}'
```

---

*Example*

```
$ a=".1.3.6.1.4.1.759.2344.454545"
$ b=".1.3.6.1.4.1.759.3234.433226"

$ awk -F. '{printf "%s","similar part is "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {first[i-1]=$i} getline; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {second[i-1]=$i} for(i=0;i<length(first);i++) {if(first[i] == second[i]) {result=result first[i]"."}} printf "%s",substr($result,0,length(result)-1)"\n"}' <<< "$a"$'\n'"$b"
similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.759
```

---

**UPDATE** In the comments, OP wants to match only until the first non-match:

```
awk -F. '{printf "%s","similar part is "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {first[i-1]=$i} getline; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {second[i-1]=$i} for(i=0;i<length(first);i++) {if(first[i] == second[i]) {result=result first[i]"."} else {i=length(first)}} printf "%s",substr($result,0,length(result)-1)"\n"}' <<< "$a"$'\n'"$b"
```

*Example*

```
$ a=".1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.2"
$ b=".1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276.2"
$ awk -F. '{printf "%s","similar part is "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {first[i-1]=$i} getline; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {second[i-1]=$i} for(i=0;i<length(first);i++) {if(first[i] == second[i]) {result=result first[i]"."} else {i=length(first)}} printf "%s",substr($result,0,length(result)-1)"\n"}' <<< "$a"$'\n'"$b"
similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.232
```

---

<sub>Tested with GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p11, GNU MP 6.0.0)</sub>

Comment: It gives me error `awk: line 1: illegal reference to array first`

Comment: I'm done, please check the current version ;)

Answer (score 3):

As I've mentioned in the comments bellow the question, I've found a somewhat simple `awk` solution: concatenate the two numberals to create one long string, replace all dots with space  ( to allow using space as default field separator in awk), and go through the string comparing field with file+half.

**Basic command**

`printf ${a[1]}${a[2]} | awk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x };}'`

I've tested this with gawk and mawk, worked in both.

Here's output with first example ( .1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256 and .1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276 ) :

```
$ printf ${a[1]}${a[2]} | awk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x };}'
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232
```

**Multiple comparisons**

If you want to compare multiple strings at the same time, concatinate them together and separate with newline in printf, then add printf at the end of awk command like so:

`printf "${a[1]}${a[2]}\n${a[3]}${a[4]}" | awk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x }; printf "\n"}'`

Output:

```
$ printf "${a[1]}${a[2]}\n${a[3]}${a[4]}" | awk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x }; printf "\n"}'
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232 # same for a[1] and a[2]
.1.3.6.1.4.1.759 # same for a[3] and a[4]
```

**Limiting the output**

Now, kos's comment appropriately noticed that OP wants only 7 numbers to be displayed. For that purpose you can add pipe to the `cut -d'.'  -f1-8` command. Like so:

`printf "${a[5]}${a[6]}" | mawk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x }; printf "\n"}' | cut -d'.' -f1-8`

Here's sample output from my terminal:

```
$ a[5]=.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.885


$ a[6]=.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.885


$ printf "${a[5]}${a[6]}" | mawk '{gsub("\\."," "); half=NF/2}; { for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x }; printf "\n"}' | cut -d'.' -f1-8
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256.885


 half) ) printf "."$x }; printf "\n"}' | cut -d'.' -f1-8                      <
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232
```

**Simplifying even further**

Again, everything can be put in an awk script

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
 gsub("\\."," "); 
 half=NF/2
}; 

{ 
 for ( x=1; x<=half; x++ ) { 
    if ( $x==$(x + half) ) printf "."$x 
  }; 
  printf "\n"
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ printf "${a[5]}${a[6]}" | num-comp.awk | cut -d'.' -f1-8                     
.1.3.6.1.4.1.232
```

**Comparison up to the first not-equal number**

Awk has a very useful function `substr(string,X,Y)` which allows cutting or "cropping" a string, from first character (x) to the ending (Y). So knowing that, let's take the two numbers as two fields of one string, and run them through while loop. We're gonna keep increasing the substring length (start to ending) until they're no longer equal. Once we encounter the unequal substrings, we quit, and print the last known equal substring.

`echo ".1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256\t.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276" | awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{ while(substr($1,1,i)==substr($2,1,i)){var=substr($1,1,i);i++};} END{print var}'`

*Special thanks to terdon for suggesting use of substr function, which I previously didn't know even existed*

Comment: Great, I like `half=NF/2` idea =)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a little `python` function that can do the job:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
def common_portion(a):
    first = a[0].split('.')
    second = a[1].split('.')
    result = []
    for (i, j) in itertools.izip(first, second):
        if i == j:
            result.append(i)
        else:
            break
    return 'Similar part is ' + '.'.join(result)
```

- We need to provide a list containing the strings we want to check as input to the function
- `first` variable will contain the parts of the first element of the input list splitted on `.` (`a[0].split`). Similarly `second` will contain the parts of the second element of list `a`.
- Then we have iterated over `first` and `second` and check the equality of each element with its same indexed counterpart, if they are same then one of them is saved in a separate list `result`. Whenever we have encountered the first difference we have broken out of the loop.
- Finally we have printed our desired result with joining the fields with `.`s (`'.'.join(result)`)

**Test :**

```
print common_portion(['.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600256', '.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600276'])

Similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.232


print common_portion(['.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.2344.454545', '.1.3.6.1.4.1.759.3234.454545'])

Similar part is .1.3.6.1.4.1.759
```